# Iphone App submission error

Tags: iphone, loader, submission

Hi My app is not being accepted by application loader in imac

error- Bundle identifier :com.steve.Assistant differs from reserved bundle identifier: Assistant

pleas help!

Answer (score 0):

The Bundle Identifier you have registered with iTunes Connect must match the one define in your app's **info.plist** file.

Looks like you need to change your app's bundle ID to: **Assistant** to match the one you created online.